# How to add dictionary inside array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have one list which is already in an object. consider following structure. I have one object like

```
data = {key: "value", key1: "value1", settings: [ ]}.
```

Now in `settings = [ ]` I have to add again an object inside that list, like:

```
settings : [{key: "value", key1: "value1"}]
```

So in total I want my data object look like

```
data = {
   key: "value", 
   key1: "value1",
   settings: [key: "value", 
   key1: "value1"]
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `var data = { key: 'value', settings: [] };` `data.settings.push({ key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' });`? You're not asking a question, we don't know what problem you have or what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have an object like this

```
const obj = { name: 'your name', age: 'your age', settings: []}
```

You can add new `key: value (hobby: 'your hobby')` to that object like that

```
obj.hobby = 'your hobby';
```

or

```
obj['hobby'] = 'your hobby';
```

or

```
obj = { ...obj, hobby: 'your hobby' };
```

And to add value to `settings`, you can add like this

```
obj['settings'].push({ key: 'value' });
```

Answer (score 2):

Array is also a type of object but instead of key value pairs it has index and value pair so I would recommend to add an object inside the array if there are multiple similar data.

```
const setting=[];
setting.push({
    key:"keyName",
    value:"the value"
});
```

something like this